# IF ELSE in where clause sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do conditional where clause that means I have three tables `rds`,
`rds_distr`,`product` and if `rds_distr_cd = 'A'` then I want to show only one row else remaining rows.

Script of tables structure and some data -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product](
    [prod_cd] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [prod_name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [prod_short_name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [uom_cd] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [inner_qty_mul_val] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
    [prod_catg_cd] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [prod_line_cd] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [prod_brand_cd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [prod_grp_cd] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [prod_subgrp_cd] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [combi_prod_flg] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [bar_code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [remark] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [active_flg] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [time_stamp] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [simpl_prod_desc] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [inside_schm_desc] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [prod_type] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [mbl_active_flg] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [hsn_cd] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [product_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [prod_cd] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[rds]    Script Date: 8/31/2017 11:42:24 AM ******/

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[rds](
    [rds_cd] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [rds_name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [rds_short_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [comp_cd] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [locn_cd] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [hq_town_cd] [int] NULL,
    [rds_type_cd] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [rds_distr_cd] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [apoint_dt] [datetime] NULL,
    [resign_dt] [datetime] NULL,
    [eff_start_dt] [datetime] NULL,
    [eff_end_dt] [datetime] NULL,
    [agreement_dt] [datetime] NULL,
    [sec_amt] [numeric](9, 2) NULL,
    [ref_no] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [area] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [block_flg] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [vacant_flg] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [active_flg] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [mobile_no_1] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mobile_no_2] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [time_stamp] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [rds_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [rds_cd] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[rds_distr]    Script Date: 8/31/2017 11:42:24 AM ******/

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[rds_distr](
    [rds_distr_seq] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [rds_cd] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [prod_line_cd] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [prod_brand_cd] [int] NULL,
    [start_dt] [datetime] NULL,
    [end_dt] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [rds_distr_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [rds_distr_seq] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[rds_distr]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [rds_distr@rds] FOREIGN KEY([rds_cd])
REFERENCES [dbo].[rds] ([rds_cd])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[rds_distr] CHECK CONSTRAINT [rds_distr@rds]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[rds] ([rds_cd], [rds_name], [rds_short_name], [comp_cd], [locn_cd], [hq_town_cd], [rds_type_cd], [rds_distr_cd], [apoint_dt], [resign_dt], [eff_start_dt], [eff_end_dt], [agreement_dt], [sec_amt], [ref_no], [area], [block_flg], [vacant_flg], [active_flg], [mobile_no_1], [mobile_no_2], [time_stamp]) VALUES (N'INMHA142', N'Amar Trading Co', N'Amar Trading Co', N'SEN', N'PNE', 50, N'R', N'A', CAST(N'2013-07-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL, CAST(N'2013-07-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', N'N', N'Y', NULL, NULL, 0)

INSERT [dbo].[rds] ([rds_cd], [rds_name], [rds_short_name], [comp_cd], [locn_cd], [hq_town_cd], [rds_type_cd], [rds_distr_cd], [apoint_dt], [resign_dt], [eff_start_dt], [eff_end_dt], [agreement_dt], [sec_amt], [ref_no], [area], [block_flg], [vacant_flg], [active_flg], [mobile_no_1], [mobile_no_2], [time_stamp]) VALUES (N'INMHA141', N'Atharv Traders', N'Atharv Traders', N'SEN', N'PNE', 152, N'A', N'A', CAST(N'2013-07-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL, CAST(N'2013-07-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', N'N', N'Y', NULL, NULL, 0)

INSERT [dbo].[rds] ([rds_cd], [rds_name], [rds_short_name], [comp_cd], [locn_cd], [hq_town_cd], [rds_type_cd], [rds_distr_cd], [apoint_dt], [resign_dt], [eff_start_dt], [eff_end_dt], [agreement_dt], [sec_amt], [ref_no], [area], [block_flg], [vacant_flg], [active_flg], [mobile_no_1], [mobile_no_2], [time_stamp]) VALUES (N'INMHM129', N'Mittal Agency', N'Mittal Agency', N'SEN', N'PNE', 50, N'R', N'B', CAST(N'2014-04-03 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL, CAST(N'2014-04-03 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', N'N', N'Y', NULL, NULL, 1500890410)

INSERT [dbo].[rds] ([rds_cd], [rds_name], [rds_short_name], [comp_cd], [locn_cd], [hq_town_cd], [rds_type_cd], [rds_distr_cd], [apoint_dt], [resign_dt], [eff_start_dt], [eff_end_dt], [agreement_dt], [sec_amt], [ref_no], [area], [block_flg], [vacant_flg], [active_flg], [mobile_no_1], [mobile_no_2], [time_stamp]) VALUES (N'INMHK083', N'Krishna Traders', N'Krishna Traders', N'SEN', N'PNE', 50, N'R', N'P', CAST(N'2014-12-26 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL, CAST(N'2014-12-26 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', N'N', N'Y', NULL, NULL, 1504005202)

set  identity_insert rds_distr on
INSERT [dbo].[rds_distr] ([rds_distr_seq], [rds_cd], [prod_line_cd], [prod_brand_cd], [start_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (1099, N'INMHK083', N'01', NULL, CAST(N'2017-08-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL)

INSERT [dbo].[rds_distr] ([rds_distr_seq], [rds_cd], [prod_line_cd], [prod_brand_cd], [start_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (1100, N'INMHK083', N'06', NULL, CAST(N'2017-08-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL)

INSERT [dbo].[rds_distr] ([rds_distr_seq], [rds_cd], [prod_line_cd], [prod_brand_cd], [start_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (1098, N'INMHM129', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2001-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL)

INSERT [dbo].[product] ([prod_cd], [prod_name], [prod_short_name], [uom_cd], [inner_qty_mul_val], [prod_catg_cd], [prod_line_cd], [prod_brand_cd], [prod_grp_cd], [prod_subgrp_cd], [combi_prod_flg], [bar_code], [remark], [active_flg], [time_stamp], [simpl_prod_desc], [inside_schm_desc], [prod_type], [mbl_active_flg], [hsn_cd]) VALUES (N'DEN101050001', N'Aps Pltnm Rt Pncl/Lpsh,Nder/10X10', N'Aps Pltnm Rt Pncl/Lpsh,Nder/10X10', N'BOX', CAST(0.10 AS Decimal(5, 2)), N'FG', N'01', 1, NULL, NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, N'Y', 1500634997, N'Aps Pltnm Rt Pncl/Lpsh,Nder/10X10 101050001', NULL, N'M', N'Y', NULL)

INSERT [dbo].[product] ([prod_cd], [prod_name], [prod_short_name], [uom_cd], [inner_qty_mul_val], [prod_catg_cd], [prod_line_cd], [prod_brand_cd], [prod_grp_cd], [prod_subgrp_cd], [combi_prod_flg], [bar_code], [remark], [active_flg], [time_stamp], [simpl_prod_desc], [inside_schm_desc], [prod_type], [mbl_active_flg], [hsn_cd]) VALUES (N'DEN101049001', N'Aps Stn Pncl/Lpsh,Nder/10X100', N'Aps Stn Pncl/Lpsh,Nder/10X10', N'BOX', CAST(0.10 AS Decimal(5, 2)), N'FG', N'01', 1, NULL, NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, N'Y', 1500634997, N'Aps Stn Pncl/Lpsh,Nder/10X100 101049001', N'Sharpner', N'M', N'Y', NULL)

INSERT [dbo].[product] ([prod_cd], [prod_name], [prod_short_name], [uom_cd], [inner_qty_mul_val], [prod_catg_cd], [prod_line_cd], [prod_brand_cd], [prod_grp_cd], [prod_subgrp_cd], [combi_prod_flg], [bar_code], [remark], [active_flg], [time_stamp], [simpl_prod_desc], [inside_schm_desc], [prod_type], [mbl_active_flg], [hsn_cd]) VALUES (N'DEN101054001', N'Aps Ntrl R/T Pncl/LPSh,NDEr/10x10', N'Aps Ntrl R/T Pncl/LPSh,NDEr/10x10', N'BOX', CAST(0.10 AS Decimal(5, 2)), N'FG', N'01', 1, NULL, NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, N'N', 1, N'Aps Ntrl R/T Pncl/LPSh,NDEr/10x10 101054001', NULL, N'M', N'N', NULL)
```

I have tried this -

```
select rds_cd, prod_cd,rds_distr_cd from 
(select distinct r.rds_cd,prod_cd,case when r.rds_distr_cd = 'A' then 0 when r.rds_distr_cd = 'B' then 1 when r.rds_distr_cd = 'P' THEN 2 END AS rds_distr_cd
                                from product p,rds r left join rds_distr rd on r.rds_cd = rd.rds_cd
                                where r.rds_distr_cd ='A'
                                AND ( r.rds_cd in ('INMHA142','INMHK083','INMHM129')
                                 and p.prod_cd in ('DEN101050001') 
                                 )
                                OR (r.rds_distr_cd in ('B','p')
                                AND  r.rds_cd = rd.rds_cd
                                and (rd.prod_brand_cd =p.prod_brand_cd
                                or rd.prod_line_cd = p.prod_line_cd)
                                and r.rds_cd in ('INMHA142','INMHK083','INMHM129')
                                 and p.prod_cd in ('DEN101050001') 
                                )) as a
                                where rds_distr_cd = IIF(rds_distr_cd = 0,0,0)
                                OR rds_distr_cd =IIF(rds_distr_cd = 1,1,1)
```

Getting result -

```
rds_cd      prod_cd        rds_distr_cd
INMHA142    DEN101050001    0
INMHM129    DEN101050001    1
```

And I want if `rds_distr_cd` is 0 then only one row should displayed else 2nd one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much of try, I got the solution

```
IF EXISTS (select distinct r.rds_cd,prod_cd, r.rds_distr_cd 
from product p,rds r 
where r.rds_distr_cd ='A'
AND r.rds_cd in ('INMHA142','INMHK083','INMHM129')
and p.prod_cd in ('DEN101050001'))
BEGIN
select distinct r.rds_cd,prod_cd, r.rds_distr_cd 
from product p,rds r 
where r.rds_distr_cd ='A'
AND r.rds_cd in ('INMHA142','INMHK083','INMHM129')
and p.prod_cd in ('DEN101050001')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
select distinct r.rds_cd,prod_cd, r.rds_distr_cd
from product p,rds r left join rds_distr rd on r.rds_cd = rd.rds_cd
where r.rds_distr_cd in ('B','p')
AND r.rds_cd in ('INMHA142','INMHK083','INMHM129')
and p.prod_cd in ('DEN101050001') 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple conditions in `where` clause with both `AND` & `OR`. It will not work as expected unless you use Parentheses properly.

Change your `where` clause to this:

```
where r.rds_distr_cd ='A'
    AND (( r.rds_cd in ('INMHA142','INMHK083','INMHM129')
           and p.prod_cd in ('DEN101050001') 
         )
         OR (r.rds_distr_cd in ('B','p')
             AND  r.rds_cd = rd.rds_cd
             and (rd.prod_brand_cd =p.prod_brand_cd
                   or rd.prod_line_cd = p.prod_line_cd
                  )
             and r.rds_cd in ('INMHA142','INMHK083','INMHM129')
             and p.prod_cd in ('DEN101050001') 
             )
        )
```

Modification: Included the `OR` as a part of second condition (inside `AND`).

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2b56/4).

Comment: Thanks for answer But If there is no record for 'A'  then it is not giving any records. It should give 2nd record.

Comment: For this condition remove rds 'INMHA142' from in

Comment: @Anagha: This was to point out the issue which is to use parantheses properly. Change your `where` clause according to your logic.

Comment: I don't think so any issue in where clause because i can not use and with rds_distr_cd  ='A'  i want data for B and P also if 'A' fails.